# Refer an integer from Service to Service

Tags: android, service, refer

I am building an app which needs to pass an integer from one service to an other service.

FirstService

```
package com.jebinga.MyApp;



import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;





public class FirstService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

int Value1=10;



@Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();





     Bundle korb=new Bundle();
        korb.putInt("Ente", Value1);

        Intent in = new Intent(FirstService.this, SecondService.class);
        in.putExtra("korb", korb);
        this.startService(in); 


         System.err.println("FirstService Value1: "+Value1); 




    }




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



}
```

SecondService

```
package com.jebinga.MyApp;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.provider.Settings.Global;
import android.util.Log;

public class SecondService extends Service{



    int Value2;








 public void onStartCommand(Intent intent, int startId){
         super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);



         Bundle zielkorb = intent.getExtras();
         int Value2 = zielkorb.getInt("Ente");



         System.err.println("SecondService Value2:="+Value2); 





         }





    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Due to the log I know that value1 in FirstService is 10 as it should be.
But value2 is 0 though it should also be 10.

What did I do wrong? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You packed a bundle into an intent, and then a value into that bundle. So you need to read them out, first the bundle, and then the value.

```
Bundle zielkorb = intent.getBundleExtra("korb");
int bValue = zielkorb.getInt("Ente");
```

Comment: That looks pretty good so far, but now I don`t get the System.err log.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're storing the value passed to the second service in the Bundle, and although you're reading it out in the second service, you're storing it in the variable bValue, and then you're outputting Value1 instead of bValue.  In the second service you can change

```
System.err.println("SecondService bValue:="+Value1);
```

to

```
System.err.println("SecondService bValue:="+bValue);
```

Comment: Ups, I am sorry, I forgot to change that. But thank you for the help, i changed it in the question.